# How can I import a module into standalone directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-standalone-components

The `imports` attribute is available on the `@Component` decorator but not on the `@Directive` decorator.

Is there another way to import a module into a standalone directive ?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to do that if you refer to https://angular.io/api/core/Directive

Although I don't really see a use case where you need to import modules

Comment: One (bad) case is to use httpClientModule. But you should not use something in directives. Use Interceptors, Guards, or Services for all things a module is needed. It's the better approach.

Comment: There are plenty of use cases when considering Angular Material modules.

Comment: Do you have a specific usecase to show us a example what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current alternative is to provide them at the root of the application with [`importProvidersFrom`](https://v15.angular.io/api/core/importProvidersFrom) (or in the router config).

```
await bootstrapApplication(RootComponent, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(NgModuleOne, NgModuleTwo)
  ]
});
```